# Setting the border color of text boxes on the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to set all text boxes border color on the form to red. I tried using

```
$('*').css('border', 'black');
```

also

```
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

   for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++)
   {

     all[i].style.backgroundColor = "Red";
   }
```

Nothing is working for me.
In the CSS file all text boxes

```
input[type=text], .htmlplusinput {
    border: 1px solid #C79988;
    padding:1px;
    width:120px;
    cursor: text;
}
input[type=text]:focus, .htmlplusinput:focus {
    border:2px solid #25a3fc;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically change them or have them red forever and always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, the `$('*')` selector matches **all** elements. If you only want text boxes, you'll want to use `$('input:text')`.

Once you have the selector correct, you need to set the colour of the border. If I recall correctly, the correct CSS property is `border-color`, so you'd do:

```
$('input:text').css('border-color', 'red');
```

Another, potentially better, solution would be to add a class to each of the elements, rather than modifying their `style` property, then use a CSS declaration for that class to control the appearance of the border:

```
$('input:text').addClass('redborder');

.redborder {
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: this true, because the selector was wrong and this is the correct selector.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

jQuery('input:text').css('borderColor', '#000');